# Practical difference between define a macro that expands to \char"XXXX and using \DeclareTextSymbol

Tags: font-encodings

This is question is only limited to using `fontspec` + `luatex` with the default `TU` encoding. The files are always in UTF-8. Is there any practical difference between, say

```
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textparagraph}       \UnicodeEncodingName{"00B6}
```

(above from `tuenc.def`) and simply

```
\def\textparagraph{\char"00B6}
```

(or perhaps a robust version).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first form actually defines `\textparagraph` to expand to

```
\TU-cmd \textparagraph \TU\textparagraph
```

(three tokens); the first is a macro that checks the current encoding and, in case it's not `TU`, does the necessary changes in order to use the version of `\textparagraph` for the current encoding (or the default). The second token is used for warning or error messages, the third one is the most important one, as it expands to

```
\char"B6
```

The shorter version wouldn't be the same, because if you happen to use `\textparagraph` in a context where a different font encoding is used (for whatever reason), you might end up with something unexpected.

Comment: Thanks. So, if say I only use TU, then the output would be exactly identical?

Comment: @YanZhou Yes, but there's no point in “simplifying” the definition. Anyway, it should be `\protected\def\textparagraph{\symbol{"B6}}`

Comment: Sure, in general I would make it protected. My situation is that sometime I need to use a private code point, say a variant of floral heart, which does not even exist in other fonts in general, and certainly not in the same point. I was wondering if there's any disadvantage to simply use `\char` in the mid of text in the rare occasions that they are needed.

Comment: @YanZhou It's better to use `\symbol` anyway. For instance, `\char"B6 x` would have no space.